# Managed Account - cannot delete due to object state

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, managed-account

I am getting an object state error on one of my managed accounts in SharePoint 2010.  I'd like to just delete that account and start fresh with a new one.

In Powershell, I run: `Remove-SPManagedAccount -Identity "DOMAIN\AccountName"`.  I get the error,

> "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

To my knowledge, I have moved all services away from that account.  Any thoughts on how I might proceed?

Comment: try to reset IIS on all servers and also clear the config cache on all server in farm?

Comment: Ah! I didn't try clearing the config cache.  I bet that's it.

Comment: did clear config cache helped?

Comment: No, but I am now quite sure I've got myself into a mess of dependencies.  I've gone from "Huh, that's weird" to "Well, time to rebuild the server."  It's time to upgrade to 2013, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code! I had a ghost managed account that I removed this way by having the object in a variable:

```
$account = Get-SPManagedAccount -Identity <ACCOUNT_NAME>
Remoeve-SPManagedAccount -Identity $account
```

Comment: This didn't solve my immediate problem, but I've upvoted because it helped me solve an unrelated issue.  Thanks!